# How to limit GPU/CPU use?

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor

I tried to render two little movie clips I dropped into the timeline to learn how to do video editing in Blender 2.8 and after a minute my computer box started beeping (which it's done once before when I tried mining Monero and it overheated and shutdown).

How can I limit how much damage Blender is doing to my box?

Comment: Hm, VSE rendering was always a single-threaded task, I doubt they change it for 2.8. Any way, you can limit CPU threads in Render tab by switching from Auto to desired number.

Comment: Please would you explain where that setting is, I don't see it in my properties.

Comment: It is in Performance rollout, see "Threads" section here: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/settings/scene/render/performance.html#threads

Comment: That's for an older Blender, and a completely different default rendering engine.

Comment: But even if I switch from Cycles to EVEE and fix 1 thread my fan still goes wild and the computer beeps. Which doesn't happen when I render video & music with multiple intense VSTs in Reaper, so I don't think it's a computer problem.

Comment: Finally, I've now noticed it only happens when the render window is showing, if I minimize it, no beeping so far and CPU usage stays around 90% only